# :documentation void-function error

Tags: debugging, functions

The following backtrace problem in being produced but cannot identify the problem correctly.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function :documentation)
  (:documentation (concat "Version and permissions of Din tools." din-about-detail))
  typex-about()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-971358> nil "/home/bard/din-1.0/din.e..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4568
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/bard/din-1.0/din.e..." "/home/bard/din-1.0/din.e..." nil nil)
  load("din")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/bard/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1963
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/bard/.emacs" "/home/bard/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157951e1402d>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x157951e14041>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

This is what I am doing

```
(defun din-message (bufname message)
   "Inserts formatted string into the `Din' dedicated buffer.
BUFNAME  Name of buffer. 
MESSAGE  Text."

   (with-current-buffer
       (get-buffer-create bufname)
     (insert message)) )

(defvar din-bufname "*Din*"
  "TODO")

(defvar din-version-license "Din Tools for Emacs.")

(defvar din-about-detail
   "Displays version number and license conditions.")

(defun din-about ()
  (:documentation
      (concat
       "Version and permissions of Din tools."
       din-about-detail))

  (din-message din-bufname din-version-license) )

(din-about)
```

Comment: It says you are trying to call a function with the name `:documentation`, now look at your code. Hint: if you would like to dynamically create a list then use `(list ...)` or use [backquote syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html)

Comment: Looked through but cannot figure out a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do in that first form in the body of `din-about`? It should get printed? Or you would like it to become a docstring?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see the error `void-function` the first thing to look for is a use of a *symbol that's not defined as a function* in a function-calling position.

That's the case here. Your code has this function call:

```lisp
(:documentation (concat "Version and permissions of Din tools." din-about-detail)
```

`documentation` is a *built-in* function in Emacs. `:documentation` is not a predefined function in Emacs. Maybe you meant `documentation`? Or maybe you meant to load some library that defines a `:documentation` function? (We can't know what you're really trying to do.)

Searching the 18.1 Elisp manual for `:documentation` shows that it's used by macro `cl-generic` -- and that's the *only* occurrence of `:documentation` in the manual.

> -- Macro: `cl-defgeneric name arguments` [`documentation`]
> [`options-and-methods`...] `&rest body`
>
> This macro defines a generic function with the specified `NAME` and
> `ARGUMENTS`.  If `BODY` is present, it provides the default
> implementation.
>
> If `DOCUMENTATION` is present (it should always be),
> it specifies the documentation string for the generic function, in
> the form **`(:documentation DOCSTRING)`**.  The optional
> `OPTIONS-AND-METHODS` can be one of the following forms:

Comment: The intention was to insert text into the function documentation.  But using `C-h f din-about` displays `Not documented`.

Comment: No clue what you mean by that comment. But yes, `din-about` has no doc string. It's not documented.

Comment: I have seen use of `:documentation` attribute to set the docstring.

Comment: You're not using any `:documentation` attribute anywhere. You're trying to call a function named `:documentation`.

Comment: Now you know what you're doing wrong -- calling `:documentation` as if it were a function. It's up to you to know what you're trying to do and find out how you want to do it.

Comment: Doing `:documentation (concat "New Tool" din-about-detail)` still gives me `Not documented`.

Comment: Your question has been answered: *"The following backtrace problem in being produced but cannot identify the problem correctly"*. The problem producing the error has been identified. If you have problems with some other code then post a separate question about that.

Comment: Perhaps, but removing the parentheses does not insert the text in the function documentation.